# TYPO3 Content Element "Image only" missing

Tags: image, typo3, typo3-7.6.x

I just installed a new 7.6.10 TYPO3 CMS and I am missing the content element "Images only". If I click on "+ Content" I only have Header Only, Text & Media, Bullet List, Table, File Links available. I have nothing configured at TS / TCE Setup (removeItems etc.). In addition, I noticed that this content type (Images) is not available to select for user groups as well.

At another system I installed some month ago (and already updated to 7.6.10) this content element is available. [image: New installation (without the element)]

Do you have an information about the appreance of this element?

[image: Old installation (same version, with this element)]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably, in your old system you're using `css_styled_content` extension, and in a newly installed `fluid_styled_content` is active by default, which replaces the former one.

And according to [TYPO3 7.5 changelog](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/core/Changelog/7.5/Important-67954-MigrateCTypesTextImageAndTextpicToTextmedia.html):

> EXT:fluid_styled_content simplifies the available CTypes which results
>   in types `text`, `image` and `textpic` being dropped in favor of type
>   `textmedia`. The relation field is changed from `image` to
>   `media_references`.

So, disabling `fluid_styled_content` and enabling `css_styled_content` should help you. Although I wouldn't recommend to do so for a fresh installation, because CEs, based on Fluid are far more flexible, than those, based on TypoScript.

Comment: makes total sense but... im using T3 9.5 over here and have both content elements available - shouldnt "Images Only" be gone within our used version?

Answer (score 0):

you could do Everything with the element "Text with Images" what you could do whit the other simpler Typoes "text" or "images Only". therefore the TYPO3 Developers decided to Unify the funktion into One Content Element. to make the Backend Simpler.

as TYPO3 now offers support for more Media types (e.g. video) they reneamed "Text with images" to "Text whith Media".

if you just Need images only you could still use the "Text with Media" element. and just don't enter any text.